# Cleaner way to wrap up jquery functions

Tags: jquery, css, function

I am building a brand editing screen with a jQuery powered preview of your colour changes.

I have set up some jQuery functions as follows but need several more of the same and was wondering if there is a cleaner way to write it to reduce repetitiveness.

```
$('input[name="p-color"]').keyup(function() {
  var pColor = ($(this).val());
  $('.custom-style-demo p').css({"color":pColor});
});
$('input[name="heading-color"]').keyup(function() {
  var headingColor = ($(this).val());
  $('.custom-style-demo h1, .custom-style-demo h2, .custom-style-demo h3').css({"color":headingColor});
});
```

http://codepen.io/rachelreveley/pen/akVkxK?editors=1010

Comment: CodeReview might be a better place for this...but check their guidelines first.

Comment: Not seen that before. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use named callbacks for your event listeners:

```
$('input[name="p-color"]').keyup(pColor);
$('input[name="heading-color"]').keyup(hColor);

function pColor() {
  var pColor = ($(this).val());
  $('.custom-style-demo p').css({"color":pColor});
};

function hColor() {
  var headingColor = ($(this).val());
  $('.custom-style-demo h1, .custom-style-demo h2, .custom-style-demo h3').css({"color":headingColor});
};
```

Then you can reference the same callback with multiple events.